# Как обработать входящий POST запрос?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Всем привет. 
Возник вопрос, как я могу обработать входящий запрос к себе на сайт(запрос будет отправлять Asterisk при входящем звонке)? 
Например, Asterisk пришлет мне POST запрос и у меня на сайте без перезагрузки страницы должно появиться всплывающее окно с данными из POST запроса.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Для этого, скорее всего, нужно использовать вебсокеты

Comment: @Shellar, посоветуете какие-то язык, на котором это лучше всего реализовать?

Comment: Думаю, что Node.JS подойдет для этого. Если не ошибаюсь, то и на питоне для джанго тоже можно сделать вебсокеты

Comment: @Shellar огромное спасибо.

Comment: вебсокет + ajax, имхо